# Meaning of note about multiply defined items

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[basic.def.odr]/15](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#15) says:

> If `D` is a template and is defined in more than one translation unit, then the preceding requirements shall apply both to names from the template's enclosing scope used in the template definition, and also to dependent names at the point of instantiation ([temp.dep]). These requirements also apply to corresponding entities defined within each definition of `D` (including the closure types of *lambda-expression*s, but excluding entities defined within default arguments or default template arguments of either D or an entity not defined within `D`). For each such entity and for `D` itself, the behavior is as if there is a single entity with a single definition, including in the application of these requirements to other entities.
> [*Note 4*: The entity is still declared in multiple translation units, and [basic.link] still applies to these declarations. **In particular, *lambda-expression*s ([expr.prim.lambda]) appearing in the type of `D` can result in the different declarations having distinct types**, and *lambda-expression*s appearing in a default argument of `D` might still denote different types in different translation units.
> — *end note*]

The emphasis is mine. I cannot understand the bolded part. How can it be that the standard specifies that the program's behavior is as if `D` has a single definition, but then also says that the multiple declarations of `D` can have distinct types? If the behavior is as if there's a single definition, then each declaration should give `D` the type from that single definition. Does anyone know of an example? (Specifically for the bolded part, not for the part after it—although that part also seems suspect, because there is an example later on about lambdas in default arguments, and in that case it's IFNDR, so evidently the conditions of this paragraph were not met in the first place.)

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood your post, but isn't that about cases like this: `using T1= struct S<decltype([]{})>; using T2= struct S<decltype([]{})>; static_assert(!std::is_same_v<T1,T2>);` https://godbolt.org/z/jo9czs1EK

Comment: @alagner No. Your example doesn't seem to have any multiply defined entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paper that added this note was [P0315R4](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0315r4.pdf). The discussion indicates that it was intended to clarify that a construct such as the following is ill-formed NDR when included in multiple TUs:

```
template <auto> struct foo { };
inline foo<+[]() {}> x;
```

The meaning of the note is as follows.  A definition of an entity consists of two kinds of constructs:

1. ones that occur only in definitions, such as the initializer of a namespace-scope variable, or the body of a function
2. ones that occur in both definitions and non-defining declarations, such as the *decl-specifier-seq*.

Whenever [basic.def.odr]/15 prescribes that multiple definitions shall behave as if only a single definition were present, it implies that constructs that fall into the first category shall be treated as if only a single copy existed across the program. So, for example, if a namespace-scope variable's **initializer** contained a lambda-expression, then that lambda-expression would have the same type in every TU, because the program is required to behave as if there's only one of them in the first place.

But the note is telling us that constructs that fall into the second category do not receive the same treatment. So when a lambda appears in the *decl-specifier-seq*, it's a different lambda in every TU; [basic.def.odr]/15 does not force the implementation to treat that lambda as if it only appears once in the program, so instead the usual rule applies: every lambda in the program is unique. The result is that every definition of `x` declares it with a different type, and [[basic.link]/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#11.1) is violated, resulting in IFNDR.

This rule is a bit counterintuitive when applied to variables, and in my opinion, the note is impossible to understand unless you already know what it means. However, when we think in terms of *functions*, the rule makes a lot of sense. When the compiler sees a lambda in the body of an inline function, it is obligated to assign the lambda a name that is based on the name of the enclosing function, so that it can ensure that it's the same lambda in every translation unit that defines the function. But if the lambda were to appear in one of the function's parameter types, then it's not really clear whether the same procedure is possible, because you need to know what the parameter types are in the first place in order to identify a function (since two functions with the same name a nevertheless different functions if their parameter-type-lists are not the same). So this distinction between definition-only and non-definition-only components of definitions is crucial in the case of inline functions, and variables are just along for the ride.